# Appinsights analytics Query to calculate Avg RPS for given duration

Tags: azure-application-insights

Below Appinsights analytics query displays the RPS w.r.t time stamp for a given duration.

let start=datetime("2021-04-13T18:35:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2021-04-13T18:52:00.000Z");
requests
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
| summarize RequestPerSecond = sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1s)

Output
"timestamp [UTC]",RequestPerSecond
"4/13/2021, 6:36:39.000 PM",2429
"4/13/2021, 6:36:40.000 PM",2292
"4/13/2021, 6:36:41.000 PM",2055

I need a AI analytics query that will calculate Average of RPS from above result and display output in below format

Metrics, AverageRequestPerSecond
RequestPerSecond,2258

where 2258 is Avg of(2429,2292,2055)

Appreciate if any one can help on this

Comment: If my post is of some help to you, could you pls accept it as the answer so that it may help others, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request per second in a specific time range means we need to got the sum count in this period and got the time difference between the start time and end time, so I tried this query:

```
let start=datetime("2021-04-28 5:40:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2021-04-28 5:42:00.000Z");
requests
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
| summarize req_count_per_sec = todecimal(sum(itemCount))/todecimal(datetime_diff('second',end,start))
```

[image]