# App Insights: Fetch Request Count grouped by Request Param

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, kql

So, I am trying to analyze performance of a system. We have 3 types of Request URLs. Something like this-->

```
1. https://<base-url>/recent?param1=string1
   https://<base-url>/recent?param2=string2
2. https://<base-url>/all?param1=string3
   https://<base-url>/all?param2=string4
3. https://<base-url>?param3=string5
```

I was using this query :

```
let start=datetime("2023-07-31T23:59:59.000Z");
let end=datetime("2023-08-01T23:59:59.000Z");
let timeGrain=5m;
let dataset=requests
    | where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
    | where client_Type != "Browser"
    | where * has "<base-url>?param1"
;
dataset
| summarize count_=sum(itemCount), avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99) by operation_Name
| union(dataset
    | summarize count_=sum(itemCount), avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99)
    | extend operation_Name="Overall")
```

I want to analyze the requests count for these URLs by particular request param. I was able to do so for particular request param.
I want to have a modular query which displays the count and duration grouped by the request params.

Comment: you've provided a sample input data set, which is helpful. it would be even more helpful if you provide the matching output to demonstrate the logic you need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I have used these URLs to reproduce and got the result by using the below given query-***

```
1. https://<base-url>/echo/recent?param1=Afreen
   https://<base-url>/echo/recent?param2=Afreen
2. https://<base-url>/echo/all?param1=Afreen
   https://<base-url>/echo/all?param2=Afreen
3. https://<base-url>/echo/resource?param1=sample
```

**`Query:`**

```
let start=datetime("2023-08-07T11:40:30.8754634Z");
let end=datetime("2023-08-09T23:59:59.000Z");
let timeGrain = 5m;
let base_url = dynamic(["https://<base-url>/echo/resource", "https://<base-url>/echo/recent", "https://<base-url>/echo/all"]);
let dataset = requests
    | where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
    | where client_Type != "Browser"
    | where url has_any (base_url) and isnotempty(split(url, "?")[1])
    | extend urlParams = tostring(parse_url(url)["Query Parameters"])
;
dataset
| summarize count_ = sum(itemCount), avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99) by urlParams
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If you want to group them by **Param_Name** then use `split(urlParams, ":")[0]`, as `parse_url(url)["Query Parameters"]` returns value in  `"param" : "value"` format.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how we can calculate the max RPS for the requests?

Comment: Please refer this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105370/appinsights-analytics-query-to-calculate-avg-rps-for-given-duration